# Set Theory Proof with Complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $A \subset B'$ and $B \subset A'$, where the prime symbol denotes the complement of each set.

Here are my thoughts:

Assume $A \cap B = \emptyset,$ since the intersection of $A$ and $B$ are empty, then an arbitrarily chosen element $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B.$ Thus $x \in A'$ and $x \in B'.$

How do I go about justifying that $A \subset B'$ and $B \subset A'?$

Maybe a direct proof is not the best way to do so?  How about a proof by contradiction?

Thank you for any help or guidance!!!

Comment: You may draw a Venn diagram to guide yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose for example that

$$a\in A\implies a\notin B\;,\;\;\text{lest}\;\;A\cap B\neq\emptyset\implies a\in B'\implies a\in A\cap B'$$

Comment: is your suggestion a proof by contradiction?  Sorry if my question seems dumb!

Comment: Not really, though the central part could be considered such. Is anything unclear ?

Comment: Take $a \in A$ thus $a \notin B$ since their intersection is empty.  This makes sense, but how do you go to the next step: lest $A \cap B \ne \emptyset?$

Comment: Well, $\;a\in B'\iff a\notin B\;$ , so we already have $\;a\in A\;$ **and also** $\;a\in B'\;$ , thus $\;a\in A\cap B'\;$

Comment: Got it now.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @mathamphetamines Any time.

Answer (score 0):

For every $x\in A$ the assumption $x\in B$ leads to $x\in A\cap B$ contradicting that this set is empty.

So we conclude that for every $x\in A$ we have $x\notin B$ wich is the same as $x\in B'$.

This proves that $A\subseteq B'$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can argue this with logic pretty well, and directly, although I'm not sure if you were looking for this answer.

Suppose $$A \subset B'$$ then, take some element in A, called $x$, and by definition: $$(x \in A)\rightarrow(x \notin B)$$ So, using the logical equivalent to the implication statement, $$\neg(x \in A) \vee \neg(x\in B)$$ And with De Morgan's law, this is equivalent to $$\neg[(x\in A) \wedge (x \in B)]$$ which is equivalent to saying $$x \notin A\cap B \rightarrow A\cap B =\emptyset$$